# Cant read php JSON encoded data in js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm calling a php script via AJAX which returns a json encoded object.

```
$.post("php/getCamera.php", {
        cam_id: identifier
        }, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            //var camera = JSON.parse(data);
            var camera = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(camera.name);
            console.log(data['name']);
            console.log(camera['name']);
    });
}
```

Here's my php script:

```
<?php
    require 'Camera.php';

    $camera = new Camera();
    if(isset($_POST["cam_id"])) {
        $cam_obj = $camera->getCamera($_POST['cam_id']);
        $cam_obj_array = get_object_vars($cam_obj);
        echo json_encode($cam_obj_array);

    }
?>
```

And here's my camera class:

```
class Camera
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    ...

}
```

In the js console, I see the encoded data, but I can't access its elements:

```
{"id":"6","name":"camera 1"}
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add 'json' at the end of your post request :

```
$.post("php/getCamera.php", {
        cam_id: identifier
        }, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(camera.name);
            console.log(data['name']);
            console.log(camera['name']);
    }, 'json');
}
```

It's a shorthand for full ajax syntax `dataType: "json"`.

Better, use `getJSON` instead of post (but then, remove 'json' :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
console.log(data.name);
```

It appears, from your log, that the data is already a JSON object, and so needs no further parsing.

Comment: It's not JSON. It's treated as a string, because the dataType has not been specified.